# JSON to VB.NET Deserialize Coding

Tags: mysql, json, vb.net

I have a column in a table where all the details of the bill are getting stored. My brother used PHP web project to do that. Now I am trying to deserialize in VB.NET

Here is the PHP code (Controller)

```
public function add_to_list() {
        $this->load->model('product_model', 'Product');
        $pdts = $this->Product->get_data(true);
        $available = $this->in_cart($this->input->post('id'));
        $cart_qty = $available ? $available : 0;
        if (!is_numeric($this->input->post('qty')) || !$this->input->post('id')) {
            $res['success'] = false;
            $res['msg'] = "Please enter the valid input";
        } else {
            $discount_percentage = $this->input->post('discount_percentage') ? $this->input->post('discount_percentage') : 0;
            $discount_rate = $pdts->selling_price * ($discount_percentage / 100);
            $final = $pdts->selling_price - $discount_rate;
            $igst = $pdts->igst;
            $igst_amt = calculate_price_by_precentage($this, $final, $pdts->igst);
            $gross = $pdts->selling_price;
            $total = $final + $igst_amt;

//            $total = $gross + $igst_amt;
            $available_qty = 5;
            $data = array(
                'id' => $pdts->id,
                'qty' => $this->input->post('qty'),
                'price' => $pdts->final_price,
                'name' => $pdts->product,
                'options' => array(
                    'product_id' => $pdts->id,
                    'product_hsn' => $pdts->hsn,
                    'product_name' => $pdts->product,
                    'product_unit' => $pdts->unit,
                    'product_rate' => $pdts->selling_price,
                    'product_mrp' => $pdts->mrp,
                    'product_gst' => $pdts->igst,
                    'product_cgst' => $pdts->cgst,
                    'product_gst_amount' => $igst_amt * $this->input->post('qty'),
                    'product_net_rate' => $pdts->cost_price,
                    'product_qty' => $this->input->post('qty'),
                    'product_free' => 0,
                    'product_discount_percentage' => $discount_percentage,
                    'product_discount_rate' => $discount_rate,
                    'product_total' => $total * $this->input->post('qty'),
                    'available_qty' => $available_qty,
                    'category' => $pdts->category,
                    'rate' => $pdts->selling_price,
                    'gross' => $gross,
                    'igst' => $igst,
                    'cgst' => $igst / 2,
                    'sgst' => $igst / 2,
                    'igst_amount' => $igst_amt,
                    'cgst_amount' => $igst_amt / 2,
                    'sgst_amount' => $igst_amt / 2,
                    'total' => $total //final_price($this, $pdts->selling_price, calculate_price_by_precentage($this, $pdts->selling_price, $pdts->discount), calculate_price_by_precentage($this, $pdts->selling_price, $pdts->sgst))
                )
            );
            $this->cart->insert($data);
            $this->pageViewData['final_discount'] = $this->input->post('discount') == '' ? '0' : $this->input->post('discount');
            $this->pageViewData['final_discount_percentage'] = $this->input->post('discount_percentage') == '' ? '0' : $this->input->post('discount_percentage');
            $this->pageViewData['ajax'] = true;
            $res['success'] = true;
            $res['msg'] = $this->load->view('order/cart_item', $this->pageViewData, true);
        }
        echo json_encode($res);
    }
```

And this is how the cell Value looks.

```
> a:1:{s:32:"b3712e169500f4754be4a6a681220a96";a:7:{s:2:"id";s:2:"69";s:3:"qty";d:1;s:5:"price";d:26.25;s:4:"name";s:28:"Seeded
> Dates 200gm Wet
> Dates";s:7:"options";a:26:{s:10:"product_id";s:2:"69";s:11:"product_hsn";s:8:"08041020";s:12:"product_name";s:28:"Seeded
> Dates 200gm Wet
> Dates";s:12:"product_unit";s:2:"GM";s:12:"product_rate";s:5:"26.25";s:11:"product_mrp";s:2:"35";s:11:"product_gst";s:2:"12";s:12:"product_cgst";s:1:"6";s:18:"product_gst_amount";d:3.149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375;s:16:"product_net_rate";s:5:"24.70";s:11:"product_qty";s:1:"1";s:12:"product_free";i:0;s:27:"product_discount_percentage";i:0;s:21:"product_discount_rate";d:0;s:13:"product_total";d:29.39999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375;s:13:"available_qty";i:5;s:8:"category";s:9:"AD
> Seeded";s:4:"rate";s:5:"26.25";s:5:"gross";s:5:"26.25";s:4:"igst";s:2:"12";s:4:"cgst";i:6;s:4:"sgst";i:6;s:11:"igst_amount";d:3.149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375;s:11:"cgst_amount";d:1.5749999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875;s:11:"sgst_amount";d:1.5749999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875;s:5:"total";d:29.39999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375;}s:5:"rowid";s:32:"b3712e169500f4754be4a6a681220a96";s:8:"subtotal";d:26.25;}}
```

That looks a lot to me. As a beginner, I need a big help from you guys to get this done.

Comment: Look for 'Newtonsoft json'. It's a good NuGet for using JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I would try and let you know.